# Show a single post on other template/page

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a site, and I need to have a separated template/page for showing just that one post.

On the home page (index) Ill loop through my categories and showing just a part of them - events - news - references.

Like this:

```
         <?php
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'Events' ) );

            if ($query->have_posts())
            {
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                        $haveEvents = true;
                        if ($eventCount < 3) {
                            $eventCount++;
                            ?>
                            <div class="event-tile">
                                <div class="event-tile-content">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <h4><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h4>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="event-tile-read-more">Lees meer</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                    }
                endwhile;
            }
```

Every section has a read all and read specific item button:
[image]
[image]

I already found out how to display all posts within a category on a separated page named: page-posts.php

On page-posts.php I simply check on which page I am and depending on which page, make a query to show the posts within a specified category

```
        $query;
        if (is_page('events')) {
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'Events' ) );
        }
        elseif (is_page('news')) {
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'News' ) );
        }

        if ($query->have_posts())
        {
etc..
```

Now what I cant figure out (not even after spending like hours on google), how to show a single post from the home page (index.php), on a single-post page...

On the action buttons I use:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="event-tile-read-more">Lees meer</a>
```

Which brings me back to the homescreen. (just started on Wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Wordpress theme `single.php` is used to display a post. If it does not exist it drops down to using your `index.php`

Try moving your `page-posts.php` to `single.php`

Comment: Ah thanks, this works, just for the record, I already was googling around like hours so thanks very much!

Comment: btw, i now use both, single for just that specific post and page-posts for all posts within a category!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its better to use archive-events.php. You can make an archive for custom posts.

With that you can do:  where events is your custom post-type. Then you land on the events archive page.

As far as i can see your problem is that the post is the global post (from your home). So maybe you can setup_postdata($post), or use the home_url('url') functions.

Comment: Hey wouter, thanks for response. I already found things like using archive but that didn't work out for me. What are the advantage, because single.php works for a post